# Column containning row numbers in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, rowcount

How do I display a column with the correct row number in my table?

I know that there was a command in SQL called ROW_COUNT but I didn't find anything about it in MYSQL.

An example of what I want can be found here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

The table automatically gives a CustomerID in a new row.

Comment: In the example link, `CustomerID` is *in* the table.  It's the PRIMARY KEY and (probably) also AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: @RocketHamat Do you mind elaborating a bit further?

Comment: What you want is to set an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field in your table.  This field will (as the name suggests) automatically increment every time you enter a new row.  This field will also be used as your table's `PRIMARY KEY`.  See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 0):

This you'll want and have to do by incrementing a variable and echoing it in the correct column with your scripting language. There is no way to get SQL to return a "row number" as far as I know.

ROW_COUNT is more for telling you how many rows got affected by an UPDATE I believe.

Answer (score 0):

There is a cute little trick which might help. Although mileage may vary with complex queries. Perhaps it will help you out

```
SET @rownumber = 0;

SELECT 
    @rownumber := @rownumber + 1 AS rownumber,
    t.*
FROM 
    tablename AS t;
```

Comment: Works.
However, I want it to keep updating automatically when I add a new data.
This is the output:http://postimg.org/image/x9tzdkbp1/
When I want to export the table to Excel it doesn't show me the rownumber column

Comment: But why don't you add an `auto_increment` field to your table?